# ダブルクオーテーションのエスケープ処理が原因によるエラー解決方法

Tags: excel

パワークエリで、kintoneのAPIを利用する処理を作成しました。
基本的な処理はうまくいったのですが、APIにPOSTするデータにダブルクオーテーションが
入っているとエラーが発生します。

ダブルクオーテーションの利用自体は問題ないAPIなので、
おそらくエスケープ処理がうまくいっていないのではと考えています。

■実際の処理部分

```
requestBody = "{""app"": " & app_id &  ",""size"": 500,""query"": """ & query & """ " & fields & "}",
```

上記にある**query**の部分に、APIに対するクエリを格納しています。
例えば

```
日付  >= LAST_MONTH()
```

といったダブルクオーテーションを使わない内容は問題なく動作します。
一方で

```
作成年月日 >= "2023-05-01"
```

とダブルクオーテーションを利用すると
不正なjson文字列です、とエラーが発生します。

```
作成年月日 >= ""2023-05-01""
作成年月日 >= \\"2023-05-01\\"
作成年月日 >= \\""2023-05-01\\""
```

など思いつくものを試していますが、動作しませんでした。

もし原因がわかるかたいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`query = "作成年月日 >= \""2023-05-01\""",`のように、`\""`と書き換えることで解決しないでしょうか？
※Kintoneは使っていないので一般的なJSONをPOSTする観点での回答です。

検証のため、下記のサンプルコードを実行してローカルサーバにPOSTされたBodyを確認してみました。

**サンプルコード**

```
let
    //query = "日付  >= LAST_MONTH()",           // 1.OK
    //query = "作成年月日 >= \\"2023-05-01\\"",   // 2.NG
    //query = "作成年月日 >= ""2023-05-01""",     // 3.構文NG
    //query = "作成年月日 >= \\""2023-05-01\\""", // 4.構文NG
    query = "作成年月日 >= \""2023-05-01\""",     // 5.OK
    body = "{""query"":""" & query & """}",
    //以下、動作用のどうでもいいコード
    ソース = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("http://127.0.0.1:8080/", [Content=Text.ToBinary(body)]),[Delimiter=",", Columns=1, Encoding=932, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    変更された型 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ソース,{{"Column1", type text}})
in
    変更された型
```

`query`変数をコメント1から5まで書き換えてそれぞれ実行した結果、Bodyとしてサーバに渡された値などは下記のようになりました。

1. `{"query":"日付  >= LAST_MONTH()"}`
2. コンパイルエラー「Expression.SyntaxError: トークン ',' が必要です。」
3. `{"query":"作成年月日 >= "2023-05-01""}`
4. `{"query":"作成年月日 >= \\"2023-05-01\\""}`
5. `{"query":"作成年月日 >= \"2023-05-01\""}`

2.は内部のダブルクォーテーションがエスケープできていないのでコード上でシンタックスエラーが発生します。
3.と4.はBodyとして渡されたJSON内部のダブルクォーテーションがエスケープできていませんので、無効なJSONになります。
1.と5.ならば、Bodyとして渡されたJSONは有効な構文です。

Answer (score 1):

PowerQueryの[テキストリテラル](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powerquery-m/m-spec-lexical-structure#text-literals)での`"`のエスケープは`""`と重ねることです。つまり、`作成年月日 >= "2023-05-01"` という文字列を作りたい場合は

```
query = "作成年月日 >= ""2023-05-01"""
```

と書きます。

次にJSON文字列の作成ですが、[`Json.FromValue`関数](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powerquery-m/json-fromvalue)を使うべきです。JSON文字列ためにどうエスケープすべきかは`Json.FromValue`関数がいい感じに仕上げてくれるので、オブジェクト構造と値に注力できます。
各変数には期待する値が格納されている前提で`{"app":app_id,"size":500,"query":query}`というディクショナリ形式のJSON文字列を作りたい場合はrecord型を使って

```
requestBody = Json.FromValue([app = app_id, size = 500, query = query])
```

と書けます。